# Failed to load the package The add-in package provided was not understood. Verify that the submitted file is a valid Office add-in package

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, appsource

I am trying to publish a MS Teams Chat bot on App Source but have came across the following error

[image: or]

Here is how my manifest.json file looks like

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.5",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "id": "0007-0007-4a9f-8163-0007",
  "packageName": "MyBOT.Manifest",
  "developer": {
    "name": "MyCompany",
    "websiteUrl": "https://MyBOT.azurewebsites.net",
    "privacyUrl": "https://MyBOT.azurewebsites.net/Privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://MyBOT.azurewebsites.net/Termsofuse",
    "mpnId": "0007"
  },
  "localizationInfo": {
    "defaultLanguageTag": "en-us"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "icon-color.png",
    "outline": "icon-outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "MyBOT",
    "full": "MyBOT Virtual Assistant"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "MyBOT",
    "full": "I am a Virtual Assistant, continuously in training to enhance my skills. Currently, I can help you by answering inquiries related to COVID-19, Zoom, Webex, Microsoft Office, Adobe, Microsoft Azure and Xbox. For questions that are not currently in my search database, I leverage the web to fetch you those information."
  },
  "accentColor": "#F9F9FA",
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "0007-0007-4a9f-8163-0007",
      "needsChannelSelector": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "scopes": [ "team", "personal", "groupchat" ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false,
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [ "team", "groupchat" ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "help",
              "description": "Provides you the list of commands that you can enter"
            },
            {
              "title": "cancel",
              "description": "Cancels the current operation"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "scopes": [ "personal", "groupchat" ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "main menu",
              "description": "This command takes you to the main menu"
            },
            {
              "title": "help",
              "description": "Provides you the list of commands that you can enter"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "token.botframework.com"
  ]
}
```

The validator gives the following error as well

[image: Validator error]

I have looked into Stackoverflow for this message as well as searched online but I am not able to get an exact article on how to fix this issue. I read about how the app has to work for all types of devices but the [manifest.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema) file doesnt show how that is to be done. Can someone forward me a template that I can build my manifest.json file on? Or am I doing something wrong altogether?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This file resolved the issue. We used AppStudio to get this file.

```
   {
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.7/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.7",
"version": "1.0.0",
"showLoadingIndicator": true,
"isFullscreen": true,
"id": "80007-8049-0007-8163-e89f9a80007",
"packageName": "com.myCompany.myBOT",
"developer": {
    "name": "myCompany Services",
    "websiteUrl": "https://myBOT.azurewebsites.net",
    "privacyUrl": "https://myBOT.azurewebsites.net/Privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://myBOT.azurewebsites.net/Termsofuse",
    "mpnId": "00000"
},
"icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
},
"name": {
    "short": "myBOT",
    "full": "myBOT Virtual Assistant"
},
"description": {
    "short": "myBOT",
    "full": "I am a Virtual Assistant, continuously in training to enhance my skills. Currently, I can help you by answering inquiries related to COVID-19, Zoom, Webex, Microsoft Office, Adobe, Microsoft Azure and Xbox. For questions that are not currently in my search database, I leverage the web to fetch you those information."
},
"accentColor": "#F9F9FA",
"bots": [
    {
        "botId": "80007-8049-0007-8163-e89f9a890007",
        "scopes": [
            "team",
            "personal",
            "groupchat"
        ],
        "supportsFiles": false,
        "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

`"IsNotificationOnly"`property is added twice in the manifest. Can you please try deleting it and check again.

[image]

Assuming that you already have two files "icon-color.png" and "icon-outline.png" along with the manifest.json in the app package zip file. Can you please verify if all three files are added to a zip files and no folder is created inside the zip package.

Comment: @SashSheen, I have updated the answer. can you please validate those conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your help but we could not resolve the issue with your suggestion! But Dana's recommendation helped.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone forward me a template that I can build my manifest.json
>   file on?

You can maybe start with this one (specifically for search extension), but you'll obviously want to change/trim/add it to do what you are actually wanting to do.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search/TeamsAppManifest/manifest.json

More [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) have other examples of manifest files.

Additionally, you may want to try and create a manifest from [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview) (MS Teams app that allows you to create them).

Comment: Thanks Dana, this recommendation helped. >>                                                      
                                                                                                                      
 **Additionally, you may want to try and create a manifest from App Studio (MS Teams app that allows you to create them)**.